# Decoding URL encoded characters in Node.js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, parsing, express

I'm sending a cookie back using `res.cookie(JSON.stringify({foo: "bar"})`, and when I look at the received cookie, the value I'm seeing is `%7B%22foo%22%3A%22bar%22%7D`. How do I decode this in a Javascript environment such as node.js?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/api/querystring.html#querystring_querystring_parse_str_sep_eq_options

Comment: you can use `decodeURIComponent` or `decodeURI`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Tushar, thanks. I saw Miro's comment which led me to querystring :)
Here's how I was able to decode the above:

```
var cookieValue = "%7B%22foo%22%3A%22bar%22%7D";
querystring.unescape(cookieValue);
//=> '{"foo":"bar"}'
JSON.parse(querystring.unescape(cookieValue));
//=> {foo: 'bar'}
```